# Excel subtraction if less than 0 not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm currently working on some basic training to not lose the ability to work with Excel.

As a programmer, I know how conditions work but Excel is giving me a hard time xD.

In the column B I have the number that was previously subtracted while I have in C the amount that is going to be subtracted next.

```
=IF(OR(ISEMPTY(B33); B33 <= 0); ""; B33-C34)
```

It works, except that the first field less than 0 will be rendered properly, but the following get `#VALUE!` as an error.

I don't know what's wrong. I'm checking if the field is empty or below or equal to 0.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Show your data or it is impossible to answer your question

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my data.

Comment: Your getting the error because you are trying to do a mathematical operation on a string. B33 is "" which in excel is a string. Try changing it to "0" and see if that works (drop the "")

Comment: It works that way but I want have these fields empty and not filled with 0. Isn't there a way to do this?

Comment: I dont understand your logic completely so cant give you a solution, but if you first do an IF() to test if B33 is a blank string and if so do your maths on a zero instead of the string, then it might work

Comment: I've just tried what you said :D Writing the solution to my question if someone has the same problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please add it as an answer and then mark it as an answer :)

Comment: I can only accept my own answers after two days. So I'll have to wait for it or you repost my answer xD You're the one who helped me after all ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
=IF( OR( B33 = ""; B33 <= C33); ""; B33-C33)
```

This will leave the fields empty without the need of having zeros all over the place ^^